# hover() and click() not playing well together

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following code,the hover function works correctly, but when clicked, loses the `clicked_no_event_box` class. Not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
/* On document.ready.. */ $(function(){

        $(".no_event_box").hover(
            function(){$(this).addClass("clicked_no_event_box");}, 
            function(){$(this).removeClass("clicked_no_event_box");}    
        );      

        $(".no_event_box").click(
            function () {$(this).addClass("clicked_no_event_box");}
        );

    });
```

Comment: presumably, it's losing the "clicked_no_event_box" class when you hover off of the element?

Comment: after clicking it, I should add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works exactly as you told it to. if you want to have class to stick you can add an alias to that class name in css.

```
.clicked_no_event_box, .new_name_to_be_used_in_click_function {
    /* definition */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `hover` function removes the class, even if you click, you could unbind the hover function once you click it.

```
$('.no_event_box').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked_no_event_box');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked_no_event_box');
    }
).click(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('clicked_no_event_box')
        .unbind('hover')
    ;
});
```